# Javascript iFrame Drop Down Hover Over

Tags: javascript, iframe

Is there a way in Javascript (no jquery) to make a hover menu that is inside a iFrame.  So it would extend beyond the iframe area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you simply cannot position content inside an iframe outside of its boundaries